# Return category name with & Ampersand doesnt work

Tags: functions, categories

I have a category named: `This & That`

However, for some strange reason my `switch` code doesn't pick it up. When I output `$firstcat` it does return `This & That` which makes it even more cumbersome.

The code works fine for other categories not containing the ampersand &.

```
function posend_text_shortcode() {
  $mycategory = get_the_category();
  $firstcat = $mycategory[0]->name;
     switch($firstcat){
      case "This & That":
       include(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/style/check.php');
      break;
   default:
       include(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/style/default.php'); 
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: And why don’t you check by term slug? It would be much safer...

Comment: how could I do this please? I am writing mycategory[0]->slug - but I still get the same problem with this category. It works for single words just fine..

Comment: ok sorry, everything seems to work fine now when I test for slug. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Take a look at my answer. There are few problems with your code, that I’ve fixed already.

Comment: Shortcodes are supposed to return their content, not display it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using titles in such comparisons is always a little bit risky - you have to deal with encodings and so on.

Much safer way is using of slugs in code, because they are url-safe.

So your code could look like this:

```
function posend_text_shortcode() {
  $mycategory = get_the_category();

  $slug = '';
  if ( ! empty($mycategory) ) {  // you have to check, if any category is assigned
      $slug = $mycategory[0]->slug;
  }

  switch($slug){
      case 'this-that': // change to real slug
          get_template_part('/inc/style/check.php'); // you should use get_template_part instead of including template parts
          break;

      default:
          get_template_part('/inc/style/default.php'); 
          break;
  }
}
```